# Correct way to initialize array of array of shortstring?

Tags: arrays, delphi, initialization

In some inherited legacy code, I've traced a problem with random garbage appearing in output to a non-initialized data structure. It's defined as:

```
MyArray: array of array of ShortString;
```

As we read values from this structure, we're sometimes getting junk that is clearly coming from a Bad Place, and which changes every time we run it.

I thought that this would be the correct way to initialize this array:

```
FillChar (MyArray, SizeOf (MyArray), 0)
```

However, as I started reading various sites, I began to doubt myself. Is that the best/correct way to initialize this array? Is 0 the correct FillValue, or should it maybe be #32?

Comment: Try execute this: `ShowMessage(IntToStr(SizeOf(MyArray)));` can you predict the result? :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Afaik shortstrings are not auto initialized. So, setlength to the right sizes, e.g.

```
setlength(myarray,10,12);
```

then set the length of all strings to 0:

```
for i:=0 to length(myarray)-1 do
  for j:=0 to length(myarray[i])-1
      setlength(myarray[i][j],0);
```

Comment: Shortstrings are not, but setting the length of a dynamic array will cause all newly allocated memory block to be filled with zeroes.

Comment: You should use for i:=low(myarray) to high(myarray) do for j:=low(myarray[i]) to high(myarray[i]) do ...

Comment: Zero filling means that SetLength is enough. Second half of answer spurious

Comment: -1 Shortstrings are auto initialized when allocated within a dynamic array. As David said, the 2 nested loops are useless just after a SetLength(), since this SetLength() will fill all allocated memory with 0, so all myarray elements will be '': SetLength() over a shortstring is the same as setting its first ansichar to #0. Very confusing answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since no size is specified this is a dynamic array. Fillchar is not the correct way to initialize those. Since they are managed types they are automatically initialized. If later you want to empty the array you can use `SetLength(MyArray,0)` or just `MyArray := nil`.

Comment: Well, if we are going to be picky, since it's a managed type, it is automatically initialised to nil.

Comment: Strictly speaking these bits are finalization suggestions, while Eric asks for initialization.

Comment: Thanks for comments, did not know you could nil-assign a dynamic array. Updated answer.